# Parenthesis too big with \hat in between

Tags: math-mode

The calculation of the correct parentheses size fails when a letter with a `\hat` accent is in between:

```
\left(\hat{x}\right)
```

Manually specifying the size of the brackets would be a lot of work as they are part of a command (statistics: expected value):

```
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\mathbb{E}\left[{#1}\right]}
```

Is there a way to modify the command to produce correctly-sized brackets?

Meta: Is there a way to have LaTeX code converted to images? Maybe it's that obvious that the help page do not mention it ...

Comment: What do you mean by correctly sized?

Comment: For direct conversion to images the [standalone](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) package together with `convert` from [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is very handy.

Comment: What does the question at the end have to do with the main question? I *strongly* suggest that you do some minimal amount of research before asking this tacked-on question.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I suspect the OP, coming from another stackexchange site, expected TeX code to automatically be rendered using MathJax (as on other sites).  Mirko, on TeX.sx, we are mostly interested by the code, hence rendering is disabled: follow zeroth's suggestions to produce an image (but you would need more reputation anyways to post it, so for this question, don't worry).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Ah, I misinterpreted completely then. My apologies to Mirko.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Thanks for the clarification of my second question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is another case showing that automatic resizing with `\left` and `\right` should be used with care. It gives unwanted spaces in some cases and wrong results in others like this.

The best thing I can suggest you is to avoid `\left` and `\right` for this command or at least to use the facilities offered by `mathtools`.

For example, you could define

```
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\newcommand{\shat}[1]{\vphantom{#1}\smash[t]{\hat{#1}}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Ex}{[}{]}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}\Ex}
```

so that

```
$\E{A}$

$\E{\hat{A}}$

$\E{\frac{A}{2}}$

$\E*{\frac{A}{2}}$

$\E*{\dfrac{A}{2}}$
```

will give the following result (`\left` and `\right` are applied only when the you call `\E*` instead of `\E`):

[image]

One can also specify explicit size of the brackets with an optional argument:

```
$\E[\big]{\hat{A}}$
```

will produce slightly bigger brackets than $\E{A}$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the \smash[t] command, that's what I was looking for.